# Logout Facebook Application

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to signup with facebook which is successfully completed. Now when I click on logout link I must be logged out from my application or from facebook. I use the following code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="test();">Logout</a>

<script>
function test() {
        alert('HI');
        FB.logout();
        window.location('https://www.example.com');
    }

</script>
```

When I click on logout the alert is working fine but it does not logout from facebook.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is Javascript, why do you need this in PHP??

Answer (score 0):

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    window.open ("http://m.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=YOUR_SITE_URL","facebook_logout","width=150,height=150");
</script>
```

this is not actual way but this alternative has served me well. may be it will help you too....